# Expected value of $e^{sP}$ where s is a complex number and $P$ is a Poisson rv

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, expected-value, characteristic-function, poisson-binomial-distribution

For each positive integer $N$, let $ B_N$ be a binomial $(N,1/3)$ random variable and $P$ be a Poisson(5) random variable. I am trying to understand the statistics of $B_P$. Could someone please hint me in the right direction to compute:
- $E[\exp[sP]]$ (where s is a complex number) 
- $E[\exp[i\theta B_P]$
I suspect that $B_P$ is a poisson binomial random variable and that $E[\exp[i\theta B_P]$ is indicator function of a poisson binomial random variable.

Comment: I think you need the self study tag.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

1. check out what a [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) is, and
2. check out [the law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the characteristic function can help me solve $E[e^{sP}]$? I understand how to solve it if $s$ is equal to $bi$ but what if $s$ is $a+bi$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(B_P = x) = \sum_{n=x}^\infty \Pr(P=n\ \&\ B_P=x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=x}^\infty e^{-5} \cdot \frac {5^n}{n!} \cdot \binom n x \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^x \left( \frac 2 3 \right)^{n-x} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-5} \cdot \frac {(5/3)^x} {x!} \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac 1 {(n-x)!} \left( \frac {10} 3 \right)^{n-x} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-5} \frac{(5/3)^x}{x!} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(10/3)^m}{m!} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-5} \cdot \frac{(5/3)^x}{x!} \cdot e^{10/3} = \frac{(5/3)^x}{x!} \cdot e^{-5/3}.
\end{align}
So $B_P \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(5/3).$

The rest will follow from what you know about the Poisson distribution.